# Right data structure or library to store a sequential workflow

Tags: python, oop, data-structures

Here's my problem:

I have a user interface that basically consists of creating events.

Each event consists of multiple phases in sequence. 
Each phase consists of tasks - these tasks are just containers for fields enter
Each tasks consists of fields to be entered by the user. So basically a task is the smallest unit of work.

Here's what it finally looks like, as an example:

```
EVENT: 
    Pre-operation-phase:
        taskA
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskB
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskC  
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
          ..
          ..
     Operation-phase:
        taskA
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskB
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskC
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskD
            a START OPERATION BUTTON that sends a request to an external service
     Post-operation-phase:
        taskA
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskB
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskC
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
       .. 
       ..
     End-phase:
        taskA
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskB
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
        taskC
            has a bunch of form fields (label: value) that are entered and saved in backend
       ..
```

Would a linked list be appropriate for this type of model? PhaseObj linked list -->
PhaseObj --> PhaseObj --> PhaseObj

Each Phase Obj has the following data linked lists (tasks)
  TaskObj --> TaskObj --> TaskObj

Each Task Obj contains fields and operations.
So, the Phase->Tasks->Fields consist of a sequential workflow. An admin could define and create
a bunch of such Workflows that could be attached to an event.

How can I store this in a NoSQL backend ?

Please recommend if this is the right data structure? or any lean third party or built in Python library to create this kind of sequential workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The most suitable data structure to use in your case is the Graph Data Structure.
check the [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).I hope this will help you